# What are the limits $\lim_{t \rightarrow \pm \infty} u(t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have already create a subject for this problem (not a similar) but I really don't know how to determine the limits of the Cauchy's problem :

\begin{cases}
x'(t) = e^{-g(x(t))^2} \\ 
x(0)=0 &
\end{cases}

with $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function of class $C^{\infty}$ and $u$ a maximal solution.

We have to calculate the limits $\lim_{t \rightarrow \pm \infty} u(t)$. Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $0<x'\le 1$ your solution indeed exists on the whole of $\Bbb R$ and is monotonically increasing. If it were bounded (above or below), it would have a limit $x^*$ (for $t\to\infty$ or $t\to-\infty$).

At the limit, $0=f(x^*)=e^{-g(x^*)^2}$ which obviously impossible.

(Consider the limit of $x(t+1)-x(t)=f(x(t+\theta(t)))$ per the mean value theorem)